# python lockf: LOCK_EX works but LOCK_SH doesn't

Tags: python, fcntl

I'm puzzled by the behaviour of the lockf function from the python fcntl library: I can't get a shared lock, while the exclusive one works:

```
In [1]: import fcntl                                                            

In [2]: f = open('file', 'w')                                                   

In [3]: fcntl.lockf(f, fcntl.LOCK_SH | fcntl.LOCK_NB)                           
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-3-5d23c6a5f968> in <module>
----> 1 fcntl.lockf(f, fcntl.LOCK_SH | fcntl.LOCK_NB)

OSError: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor

In [4]: fcntl.lockf(f, fcntl.LOCK_EX | fcntl.LOCK_NB)                           

In [5]:
```

The error code corresponds to EBADF from the http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/lockf.3.html, which does not make much sense, as f is a writable open file descriptor.

Any ideas?

(Python 3.6.9, Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fcntl.lockf` sure looks like it should be a wrapper around POSIX `lockf`, but it's not. POSIX `lockf` doesn't even have shared locks.

`fcntl.lockf` is a wrapper around POSIX [`fcntl`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/fcntl.html). `LOCK_SH` corresponds to `F_RDLCK`, which requires a file descriptor opened for **reading**.

While you're at it, you might want to read about [the problems with file locking](http://0pointer.de/blog/projects/locking.html).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I read that post, and this one as well: https://gavv.github.io/articles/file-locks/ (mentioning it here, as it is super informative, even though it does not deal with what Python did with lockf).

Comment: Another comment for people from the future: opening with `a+` allows for both types of locks on the same file descriptor.